# Handling exceptions in Spring MVC along with Rest API

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, url-routing, exceptionhandler

I am using `@ControllerAdvice` annotation for defining exceptions at application level. Now the problem is I am having two `@ControllerAdvice` classes, one for REST and one for the normal web app. When I define `@ExceptionHandler` for `Exception.class` in both, only the first one is considered. How do I separate both? Or how can I catch an Exception and determine from where it has occured? Is there a way or else do I need to use controller-specific exception handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating a custom exceptions for my application and  giving one exception handler method for each of them with @exception handler.

I also used aspects to make sure that every exception is converted to any of the custom exceptions.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExceptionInterceptor {

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "within(x.y.package..*)", throwing = "t")
    public void toRuntimeException(Throwable t)
            throws ApplicationException1, ApplicationException2,ApplicationException3 {
        if (t instanceof ApplicationException1) {

            throw (ApplicationException1) t;
        } else if (t instanceof ApplicationException2) {

            throw (ApplicationException2) t;
        }  else 
            throw (ApplicationException3) t;
        }
}
```

These will transfer control to @controlleradvice.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what you are doing here? How does this transfer control to either one of your ControllerAdvice classes?

Answer (score -1):

I noticed this have been left for a month or so, so it might be old. But this article may help http://www.baeldung.com/2013/01/31/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring-3-2/.

The section 3.5 is probably what you are looking for, a custom Exception Resolver.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I solved it using aspects so that all the exceptions will be thrown to single place.

Comment: I think this does not explain how to do exception handling for both REST APIs  and HTML pages in the same Spring App. -1